# Equicontinuity of a family which is a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, equicontinuity

If we consider a family of functions to be a sequence of functions, do we need to require in the definition that $$|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|<\epsilon$$ holds for $n$ large? Or should it hold for all $n$?

The general definition implies that it should hold for all $n$. But I found two implicit answers in Rudin which contradict each other. The proof of Theorem 7.24 implies that the above should hold for $n$ large, where as the proof of Theorem 7.25 says it should hold for all $n$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any finite set of continuous functions on compact $K$ is equicontinuous, so  stating  that the sequence is ultimately equicontinuous is to state that the  whole sequence equicontinuous, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read correctly, Rudin mentioned that $|f_{i}(x)-f_{i}(y)| < \epsilon$ for all $1 \leq i \leq N$. He then showed the same thing for all $i > N$. So yes, it does have to hold for all $n$.

Comment: More generally, if $\mathcal{F} \subseteq C(K)$ is equicontinuous and $\{f_{1},\dots,f_{N}\} \subseteq C(K)$ is any finite set, then $\{f_{1},\dots,f_{N}\} \cup \mathcal{F}$ is equicontinuous.  (I'm assuming $K$ is compact, as in Rudin.)

Answer (score 0):

In 7.24 Theorem, the equicontinuity of $\{f_n\}$ is the part of conclusion. So, Rudin proves it by using uniform continuity in conjunction with uniform convergence. Using uniform continuity, he proves that $|f_{i}(x)-f_{i}(y)| < \varepsilon$ for all $1 \leq i \leq N$, and using uniform convergence, he proves that $|f_{i}(x)-f_{i}(y)| < \varepsilon$ for all $i>N$.

However, in 7.25 Theorem, the equicontinuity of $\{f_n\}$ is a given hypothesis. So, Rudin uses the fact that $|f_{n}(x)-f_{n}(y)| < \varepsilon$ for all $n$ directly.